# Package migration from version 8 to version 6 failed with error 0xC001700A

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

SSIS package built in VS 2013 (v 12.0.31101)
DTSExec run on SQL Server 2014

> Description: Package migration from version 8 to version 6 failed
>   with error 0xC001700A "The version number in the package is not valid.
>   The version number cannot be greater than current version number.".

I see lots of google results for the above when people use SQL 2012, but I am on 2014 and can find no support. The versions should match (i.e. both be package version 8)

```
select @@version
```

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (RTM-CU14) (KB3158271) - 12.0.2569.0 (X64) 
>     May 27 2016 15:06:08    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>     Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

Additional info - looks like it is running an older DTSExec, pehaps from a now deleted instance of sql 2012. How would I fix/repoint to 2014?

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version **11.0.2100.60**
>   for 64-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found that I could force it to use the correct dtexec as follows:

> Go to PATH environmental variable and edit it in such a way that
>   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn" path appears well
>   before the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn" path.

Followed by restarting the SQL Server service. Now it shows correct version:

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 12.0.2569.0
>   for 64-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 1):

use of the correct deployment wizard helps resolve the issue.

1. Use correct target sql version.
2. If your server is of 32 bit , make sure to "Run64Bitruntime" property to False.
3. If you deploy directly from your solution deployment wizard , it should create no problem.
4. Build and rebuild the solution and deplioy.
5. If you are sending .ispac to someone who will deploy then there could be a problem.
6. Make sure the correct version of deployment wizard is used while deploying the ispac as it automatically converts the package version value.

select * from SSISDB.internal.packages

-> For Sql server version 2012 packageformatversion is 6
-> For Sql server version 2014 and above packageformatversion is 8